# Display correctly resized image or scale larger on page?

Tags: html, performance, http

Hi more of a question of opinion or best practice here. I am building a site that has a page with a carousel at the top under which there is an accordion. The accordion includes all of the same images as the carousel but at half the size.

For performance would it be best to use the same images as the carousel as then there will only be one http call for that asset or generate the correct size image variations for all the relevant slots but increase the amount of requests for the same asset?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same images at both places and re-size them using height and width attributes of img tag